# Text overflow in an arrow shaped div

Tags: html, css

This is the **HTML**:

```
<div class="arrow"> 
i need to hide the overflown text which comes out of the div 
</div>
```

and the corresponding **CSS** is:

```
.arrow {
  width: 5%;
  position: relative;   
}

.arrow:before {
   content: " ";
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: -0.58em;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: .585em .585em .585em 0;
 }
```

I need to hide the overflowing text.

If I apply `overflow:hidden` the pointed triangle disappears instead of the text.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: A tip `:before` should go along to `.arrow`

Comment: i didnt get what u meant can u give it in the form of code

Comment: i dont want multilines of text

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wnGmt/ the height of the div is not fixed and i dont want the text to appear in multi lines the text which crosses one line must be hidden

Answer (score 2):

The following might work if you wrap your content in an extra element:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <span>i need to hide the overflown 
          text which comes out of the div</span>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```css
.arrow {
    width: 5%;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow:before {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.58em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .585em .585em .585em 0;
    border-color: red yellow green blue;
}
.arrow span {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tweaked the border colors since the arrow shape was not obvious, but you can fix that easily enough.

I wrapped the text in a `span`, set `white-space: nowrap` to get the text to form a single line and then set `overflow: hidden` to hide any text wider than the width.  Set `display: block` or else use a `div` instead of a `span`.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nukeL/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without adding any more elements to your html:

- Added `white-space: nowrap` to keep the text from wrapping
- Added `padding-left: 1em` to make room for the arrow
- Set `left: 0` for your arrow

and fixed the arrow display...

**CSS**

```
.arrow {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 10%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.arrow:before {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: .585em solid transparent;
    border-top: .585em solid transparent;
    border-left: .585em solid black;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGGLf/2/)

Comment: This works because, without the negative left value, the pseudo-element is within the visible space of the `.arrow` element.  Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a container inside the arrow to constrain your text (assuming fixed height).

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="container">
    I need to hide the overflown text which comes out of the div.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 30px; /** assuming fixed height here. **/
  max-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xBM88/

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any pointed triangle in your fiddle.

But I would suggest you to take a look at [**text-overflow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

```
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;  //don't hide content, instead render an ellipsis ("...")
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnGmt/1/)